# Mock an internally used function from a sub package with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, monorepo, lerna

I have a Lerna monorepo, a `@project/shared-component` sub package and a `@project/consumer` sub package. The `@project/shared-component` package exposes a `SharedComponent` react component, which internally uses a `useData` hook which is also exposed. In the `@project/consumer`, I have a `ConsumerComponent` which renders the `SharedComponent` component. In `@project/consumer`, I also have a test which tests the `ConsumerComponent`. There I want to mock the innards of the `useData` hook with Jest. This is the code I use to mock:

```js
jest.mock("@project/shared-component", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("@project/shared-component"),
  useData: jest.fn(),
}));
```

This would be possible if everything would be in one package, but since I am trying to mock a function that is internally used in the mocked package, the `SharedComponent` uses the actual function rather than the mocked one. Does anyone have an idea on how to mock the `useData` hook internally used by `SharedComponent`? Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem, and moved dependencies into the shared component via dependency injection, so I could mock the dependency in my test easier.  Therefore the useData is a dependency, and can be set many ways (constructor, method, etc.) and then it is easy to mock.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. The comment by @Steven Scott does indeed seem like a proper solution, but in my case, extracting and then injecting the dependencies takes away the need to extract the shared components in the first place because my consumer components would then need to know about the dependencies, and to be honest, I don't like the idea of changing my code purely for the tests, since I don't use my hooks in that way.

@Lukas, If you find/found a way in the meantime, please post it back here. My current solution is to just test the `SharedComponent` thoroughly in it's package, and then just test that my `ConsumerComponent` calls the `SharedComponent` correctly. Then I depend on the idea that I can use (and trust) every component I use because they are properly tested internally.

But again, if you find a better solution, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: This is fine, you are unit testing and not integration testing.